# When to use as to cast objects?

Tags: c#, object, polymorphism

I am slightly confused on wether I am approaching this correctly. Let's say I have a roll-play game, where players can defeat monsters and collect items, here is *some* of my player class: (c#)

```
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double life { get; set; }
    public double power { get; set; }
    public Swords weapon { get; set; } // their Held weapon
    private List<Items> items; //Represents their backpack
    private Monster monster; //The monster they are currently facing.

    public Player(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        life = 1000;
        power = 10;
        weapon = new Swords("Fists", 100, 1); //The power of the weapon. Can only punch at the start
        items = new List<Items>();
    }

    public void addItem(Items i)
    {
        items.Add(i);
    }
```

And then look at this method I have in my player class:

```
public void equiptSword() //
    {
        Swords tempSword;
        foreach (Items i in items)
        { 
            if (i is Swords)
            {
                tempSword = i as Swords;
                tempSword.equiptItem(this); 
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see I have a super/base class called items, everything derives from this. When a player defeats a monster they obtain a sword, which I add to the list of items(their backpack). The base class has no virtual method of `equiptItem()`, only the swords have this method. Therefore, I cannot just type type `items[5].equiptItem()`. This means I am having to use an if statement that checks if i is a sword, and if it is, cast it as a sword and then equipt it. But there's something about this that makes me think I am approaching it incorrectly, sure, I could just add a virtual method to the base class Items, but then again I don't want all items to have the option to be equiptable.

Sorry, if I am rambling.

What do you think, am I approaching this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are on the right track.

I agree that you don't want to add a whole bunch of unrelated stuff to `Item`.

I think you could come up with some broad interfaces that would simplify the code somewhat.

For example, you could have an `IEquippable` interface which had an `Equip()` method. Then any equippable Item would implement `IEquippable`.

You could have other interfaces to represent other things in a similar manner, such as `IConsumable` and `IPortable`.

Then in you code, you can do things like:

```
IEquippable equippable = item as IEquippable;

if (equippable != null)
    equippable.Equip(); /// Etc
```

Using Linq you can write stuff like:

```
foreach (var equippableItem in inventoryItems.OfType<IEquippable>())
{
    equippableItem.Equip();
}
```

However, you should try to keep strongly-typed collections where possible - but of course an inventory is by its very nature a heterogeneous collection.

Also note that using interfaces to represent these concepts allows you to have items which implement more than one of them, such as a potion which is `IConsumable` and `IPortable`.

It might be a good idea to put the logic that does this into separate classes that hide it all away; for example, an `Equipper` class that handles equipping things.

One thing though - I don't see why you would have to equip the sword by looping through the bag. I would have thought you'd have a set of items (lets call it `Loot`) dropped by the monster which you would handle more like this:

```
void handleLoot(Loot loot)
{
    // Get first sword dropped, or null if none.
    var sword = Loot.Items.OfType<Sword>().FirstOrDefault();

    if (sword != null) // Sword implements IEquippable so we can:
        sword.Equip(); // just equip it.
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I can see how an interface will make this more manageable.